# Sublime Text Tab Completion Double Brackets

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Perhaps simple to fix, but in my Sublime when I tab complete it adds an additional angle bracket for HTML, this making it pretty useless as a time saver.

e.g.

```
<h1>header</h1>
```

becomes

```
<<h1>header</h1>
```

Let me know if you need any additional information to troubleshoot this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported dozens of times and is a known issue with the current version of Zencoding.  More info [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7489&p=34995).

Comment: This should have been made a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No.  It's most definitely an answer since the link provides details to how to fix the problem and another link to the new version of zencoding.

Comment: Hi, It was an issue with Zen by the looks of it. Only my work machine was affected. Valjas' tip is going to come in handy too... Cheers you two

Answer (score 6):

Don't type the opening bracket:

i.e.

```
<h1 + tab
```

Instead just type:

```
h1 + tab
```

Autocompletion will work and you won't get the extra `<`

Comment: Thanks for this. Will save me a lot of time in the long run, and those hints are the best :-)